# xpages - prevent SSJS on page load in CSJS

Tags: xpages

I have some SSJS within CSJS onclick event of a button.  Is there any way to prevent this SSJS from executing during page load?

Thanks

Comment: You're probably facing common mistake - CSJS contains SSJS parts - and it is executed when page renders. You should not use "active" scripts in these events. Also, some source sample would be helpful to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by checking *facesContext.getRenderResponse()*. If it is *true*, the page is reloaded, otherwise it is *false*. The flag is not set correctly but gives you an easy way to check if the page is loaded or not.

Here is an example XPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
   <xp:button value="Reload CSJS" id="buttonReloadCSJS">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
         <xp:this.script>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
               facesContext.getRenderResponse()?"alert('NotOnLoad');":"alert('OnLoad')";
            }]]>
         </xp:this.script>
      </xp:eventHandler>
   </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

If you open the XPage and click the button, the page will be reloaded and you will have another CSJS code.

**EDIT:**
Here is another way to calculate code only if the button was partial refreshed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">

   <xp:div id="refreshMe">
      <xp:button value="Reload CSJS" id="buttonReloadCSJS">
         <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="refreshMe">
            <xp:this.script>
               <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                  var ajax = new com.ibm.xsp.ajax.AjaxUtil();
                  if( ajax.isAjaxPartialRefresh(facesContext) == true){
                     return "alert('Refreshed')";
                  }
               }]]>
            </xp:this.script>
         </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:button>
   </xp:div>

</xp:view>
```